# how to load page by python selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I can view page by any browser, I can only view blank when I open that by Selenium, I found there is javaScript as below, I guess that I need to run this code, what can I do next?

```
<body>
    <script>
        !function(){
            var e=document.createElement(“iframe”);
            function n(){
                var n=e.contentDocument||e.contentWindow.document;
                if(n){
                    var t=n.createElement(“script”);
                    t.nonce=“”,t.innerHTML=“window[‘__CF$cv$params’]={r:‘7e88f63d224cc37d’,m:‘JpppFqs3NGPEA327hy7XHbhTbKXvZxzVh_Th60Z2NO4-1689664824-0-AdsfsWHmOM/vJvQfOZX4DHS1zxskac6BpgnnirFZJp3k’};
                    _cpo=document.createElement(‘script’);
                    _cpo.nonce=‘’,_cpo.src=‘/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/scripts/invisible.js’,document.getElementsByTagName(‘head’)[0].appendChild(_cpo);“,n.getElementsByTagName(“head”)[0].appendChild(t)}}if(e.height=1,e.width=1,e.style.position=“absolute”,e.style.top=0,e.style.left=0,e.style.border=“none”,e.style.visibility=“hidden”,document.body.appendChild(e),“loading”!==document.readyState)n();
                else if(window.addEventListener)
                    document.addEventListener(“DOMContentLoaded”,n);
                else{
                    var t=document.onreadystatechange||function(){};
                    document.onreadystatechange=function(e){
                        t(e),“loading”!==document.readyState&&(document.onreadystatechange=t,n())
                    }
            }
        }();
    </script>
    ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the html elements are loaded with a javascript, you don't need to run the javascript.
Instead, you can programmatically wait till the entire page is loaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

dr = webdriver.Chrome()
dr.get('www.website.com')

# wait for 10 secs and get element
ele = wait(dr,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"<class_name>")))

# if you want to interact with any element
ele.click()

dr.quit()
```

If at all in some cases, you want to execute the javascript, Even that is possible with selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
dr = webdriver.Chrome()

js = '''
<script>
    !function(){
        var e=document.createElement(“iframe”);
        function n(){
            var n=e.contentDocument||e.contentWindow.document;
            if(n){
                var t=n.createElement(“script”);
                t.nonce=“”,t.innerHTML=“window[‘__CF$cv$params’]={r:‘7e88f63d224cc37d’,m:‘JpppFqs3NGPEA327hy7XHbhTbKXvZxzVh_Th60Z2NO4-1689664824-0-AdsfsWHmOM/vJvQfOZX4DHS1zxskac6BpgnnirFZJp3k’};
                _cpo=document.createElement(‘script’);
                _cpo.nonce=‘’,_cpo.src=‘/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/scripts/invisible.js’,document.getElementsByTagName(‘head’)[0].appendChild(_cpo);“,n.getElementsByTagName(“head”)[0].appendChild(t)}}       if(e.height=1,e.width=1,e.style.position=“absolute”,e.style.top=0,e.style.left=0,e.style.border=“none”,e.style.visibility=“hidden”,document.body.appendChild(e),“loading”!==document.readyState)n();
            else if(window.addEventListener)
                document.addEventListener(“DOMContentLoaded”,n);
            else{
                var t=document.onreadystatechange||function(){};
                document.onreadystatechange=function(e){
                    t(e),“loading”!==document.readyState&&(document.onreadystatechange=t,n())
                }
        }
    }();
    </script>
'''
dr.execute_script(js)
```

Comment: I tried to use wait(dr,10).until(), that doesn't work, even I waited more than 10 minutes! I think page will check something to decide if load rest of page...
I want to run that javascript in page not hard coding, because that script might be variable not fixed code...

Comment: I guess the page post page again when I open that page in browser, but not auto post if I open it by python selenium. How can I reload page by POST?

Comment: I also found `Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://ddys.pro/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/scripts/invisible.js”. blank:1:1
The resource from “https://ddys.pro/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/scripts/invisible.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).`, do I have to set `X-Content-Type-Options` when I driver.get(url)?